# Objc - Is @private directive needed anymore in the objective-c language?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, private-members

I was just wondering if there is any need besides backwards compatibility to keep the @private keyword in objective-c, since class extensions provide a much better way to declare your private iVars. Are there any other reasons for keeping the @private directive?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32-bit x86 architecture still requires declaring ivars in the primary `@interface` block. The ability to synthesize ivars (via properties or class extensions or on the `@implementation`) is only available for 64-bit x86 and ARM architectures (and, presumably, any future architecture as well).

Comment: I didn't know about that, what uses the 32-bit x86 architecture today?

Comment: @OscarGomez: Nothing today. Older macs. Anything that had a CPU up to the Core Duo is 32-bit. Anything with a Core 2 Duo and later is 64-bit.

Comment: @OscarGomez: Also, the 32-bit PPC architecture also has this limitation, but you must be doing something quite esoteric if you're still compiling Obj-C for PPC today.

Comment: That's what I though, ARM Is 32 bit right?. I don't understand why class extensions ivars could not also be available for 32-bit x86 architecture.

Comment: @Oscar: Strictly, it's not the architecture, but the runtime. Apple could not support older systems with "ObjC 2.0" (for reasons which Kevin gives in the next comment). Nothing technical prevents a fork of the runtime, or GNUStep, e.g., from providing non-fragile ivars on 32-bit systems.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: It's not that they discontinued it. 32-bit was still alive and kicking when Obj-C 2.0 was introduced. The problem is fixing the fragile base-class problem is an incompatible ABI change and would have completely removed any backwards compatibility with everything compiled before Obj-C 2.0 was available

Comment: In other words, if they tried to fix it for 32-bit, every single 32-bit program ever compiled for the platform would fail to launch.

Comment: @Kevin: You're right, "discontinued" was the wrong word, because ObjC 2.0 never supported 32-bit.